# finding non anchored variable in oracle package

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11gr2, data-dictionary

How can we find all the variables in the package, that are not declared as anchored.
Suppose I have a package as shown below:

```
create or replace pkg body test 
is 
 TYPE AnEntry IS RECORD (
  term    VARCHAR2(20),   --TERM IS NOT  ANCHORED 
  meaning VARCHAR2(200));  --MEANING IS NOT ANCHORED 

 procedure abc is 
  v_emp_id number;-- here v_emp_id is not an anchored variable 
 begin


 end abc;

end test;
```

I need a sql query, to which i pass the package name, and it will given me all the list of `non anchored variables` with `line number`.

Do we have any `data dictionary views`, which have such granular details, I have seen `user_identifiers` table, which gives granular details, but I can't such things to satisfy my condition.

Comment: I hate to ask but why? If you're just trying to find something then I guess you might be looking for variables that don't comply with a coding standard?? but you're not going to use this in code are you?

Comment: what do you mean by 'anchord'?

Comment: @JensSchauder:If you declare variable like `emp.empid%TYPE`,then this is anchored declaration of any variable.

Comment: @Ben:Actually i am tring to create a tool ,which find these variables which are not anchored declared .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realistically, you'd need to go through the `DBA_SOURCE` view looking for strings like `VARCHAR2(`, `NUMBER` or `DATE;`.